# How to acess another member class object from within class

Tags: c++, c++11

Im relatively new to cpp. Im currently trying to write new testcases for a class foo,

```
Class foo2 { 
Public:
 Getsomevariable();
 // do something
}

Class foo {
Private:
Foo2 foo2_obj;
}

Class testfoo {
 protected:
 Foo foo_obj;
 }

TEST_F(testfoo, getsomevariabletest)
{ // ? How to access getsomevariable method of foo2 from foo_obj
 Temp = foo_obj?
 ASSERT_EQ(100,Temp);
 }
```

Now Im testing using object of foo, but how should I be able to access foo2.Getsomevariable() from foo object?

Please help

Comment: foo2_obj.Getsonevaraible();

Comment: `foo2_obj.Getsomevariable()`

Comment: Make your "test case" a class method, so it has access to private class members.

Answer (score 0):

I created a main to demonstrate the purposes of this, but tweak it for your own intended purpose.

```
class foo2 {
    public:
    std::string Getsomevariable() {
        return "Hey!";
    }
};

class foo {
    public:
        foo2 foo2_obj;
};

int main() {

    foo f;
    std::cout << f.foo2_obj.Getsomevariable();

}
```

Comment: Foo2_obj is private member of foo.

Comment: @TT make it public or create an accessor.